# Why is TypeScript inferring wrong type in this case?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following code and typescript infers the type of variable `d` to be a `string`, but infact it should have been a `string | number`. I understand that this happens due to a feature of typescript called type narrowing due to assignments. But it can get quite unsafe (as is implied in the following code). How to opt out of this behaviour?

```
interface Z {
    name: string | number;
}

const f = (z: Z) => {
    z.name = 200;
};

let z: Z = {
    name: 2,
};

z.name = '2';

f(z);

const d = z.name;
```

Edit: Seems like one way to get around with this is to have some linter making parameter non-modifiable (but this is very restricting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this behavior is "configurable".

Your `f` function is changing the type of a property of it's argument, `z`, and I'm guessing the compiler doesn't check that deep.

If you want the typing to be correct, you're going to have to tell TypeScript you're doing something to the variable.

This would work:

```
interface Z { name: string | number; }

const f = (z: Z) => {
    z.name = 200;
    return z;
};

let z: Z = { name: 2 };

z.name = '2';

z = f(z);

const d = z.name;
```

replacing `z` with the returned value makes TS "persist" the type change that occurs in `f(z)`.

Or this:

```
interface Zbase { name: any }
interface Z       extends Zbase { name: string | number; }
interface Znumber extends Zbase { name: number; }
interface Zstring extends Zbase { name: string; }

const f = (z: Z) => { z.name = 200; };
let z: Z = { name: 2 };

z.name = '2';

f(z);

const d = (z as Znumber).name;
```

Now, none of this is very pretty, but I usually take that as a sign I'm doing something wrong when writing TS:

Why can a `name` be a `number` or a `string`?
How else can I approach `<requirement>`, so I can properly type my properties?